# WCF An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response

Tags: wcf, datacontract, datamember

Here's what my WCF service should be returning. When I command PaymentData out of ResponseModel and add other DataMembers in that class it works.

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public PaymentData PaymentData { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the `PaymentData` class:

```
[DataContract]
public class PaymentData
{
    [DataMember]
    public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// If true, then the CardNumber property will contain the token
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsCardNumberTokenized { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Number on back of credit cards. This value CANNOT be stored anywhere
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string CardSecurityValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public CardSecurityPresence CardSecurityPresence { get; set; }
}
```

... and the enums defined in the `PaymentData` class

```
[DataContract(Name = "CardSecurityPresenceEnum")]
public enum CardSecurityPresence
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "1")]
    IsPresent = 1,
    [EnumMember(Value = "2")]
    Illegible = 2,
    [EnumMember(Value = "9")]
    NoCodeOnCard = 9,
    [EnumMember(Value = " ")]
    NotSent
}

[DataContract(Name = "PaymentTypeEnum")]
public enum PaymentType
{
    [EnumMember]
    Visa = CMPWSApiService.TransactionMop.VI,
    [EnumMember]
    MasterCard = CMPWSApiService.TransactionMop.MC,
    [EnumMember]
    AmericanExpress = CMPWSApiService.TransactionMop.AX,
    [EnumMember]
    Discover = CMPWSApiService.TransactionMop.DI,
    [EnumMember]
    PayPal = CMPWSApiService.TransactionMop.PP,
    [EnumMember]
    BillMeLater = CMPWSApiService.TransactionMop.BL
}
```

Does the serialization not like that my variable names have the same names as their classes?

Here's the error from the WCFTest Client:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   [service url omitted]. This
>   could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being
>   aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See
>   server logs for more details.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at ICreditCardService.TestAuth()    at
>   CreditCardServiceClient.TestAuth()
>
> Inner Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected
>   error occurred on a receive.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
> Inner Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)    at
>   System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean
>   userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
>
> Inner Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)

Comment: It appears to be from the CardSecurityPresenceEnum. When I comment that out it works. Why is that enum giving me issues?

Comment: Apparently I have to set NotSent to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CardSecurityPresenceEnum` I had a enum member called `NotSent` that was not initialized to a value. For some reason that was hanging things up.