# WCF Client fails when defining enum values explicitly

Tags: .net, wcf, enums, datacontract

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342117/wcf-an-error-occurred-while-receiving-the-http-response) but with one interesting difference. I have defined all values explicitly and it still doesn't work. Also I try to avoid contract attributes, if possible.

So what it all looks like.
I define a contract that has a property of enum type. The enum is

```
public enum ErrorCodes
{
    GeneralError = 1,
    ValidationError = 2,
    AuthenticationError = 3
}
```

And then client fails with errror:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/MyTestAppService/SomeService.svc/soap. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at MyTestApp.ISomeService.TestMethod(TestRequest request)
```

When I remove all explicit values, it works:

```
public enum ErrorCodes
{
    GeneralError,
    ValidationError,
    AuthenticationError
}
```

Comment: Did you decorate the enums with [EnumMember(Value = "1")]`, as per the linked question?

Comment: no, I'm trying to avoid it

Comment: Why?  The underlying cause of your issue is most likely a serialization error, so why do you want to avoid the `[DataContract]` family of attributes?

Comment: see my comment to @Tim's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally found a really simple solution. It seems strange that the documentation doesn't mention it.

The enum only has to have a **default value** and everything works like a charm! Don't know if it's a nice bug or undocumented feature.

```
public enum ErrorCodes
{
    Default = 0, // without this member WCF fails
    GeneralError = 1,
    ValidationError = 2,
    AuthenticationError = 3
}
```

How did I come to that? I simply tried other enum and it worked even having explicit values and fortunately the difference was that it has the default.

Comment: AAARGH !!! whole day lost ... now there's a new entry in my enum: `SomeEnum.MakeWcfHappy = 0;` :)

Answer (score 3):

In the answer you linked to, the enums where decorated with `[EnumMember]` and the value set, like this:

```
[DataContract]
public enum ErrorCodes
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "1")]
    GeneralError = 1,
    [EnumMember(Value = "2")]
    ValidationError = 2,
    [EnumMember(Value = "3")]
    AuthenticationError = 3
}
```

Your posted code appears to be missing those attributes.

**ADDED**

While you do not need to use the `[EnumMember]` attribute (per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), that applies **only** to simple enumerations.  Under the "Simple Enumerations" section, it says:

`You can use simple enumerations when you *do not need to customize* the enumeration's data contract name and namespace and the **enumeration member values**.`

Comment: according to the msdn the attributes can be omitted https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Do you think there is no way to avoid the attributes? Imagine there are many members having hex values and in this case duplicating the values in the attributes is not elegant. I try to avoid that

Comment: @neleus - See my addition to the answer above.

Comment: Hmm, that's pity. Do you think there is no way to avoid the attributes?

Comment: In this situation, I highly doubt it.  The amount of time it would take to figure out an alternative is probably less than the amount of time it would take to decorate the enum.  Why do you want to avoid the attributes?

Comment: See my comment above. My example is simplified and there are bigger Enums.

Comment: @neleus - Ah.  I see the desire to avoid now, but I don't see a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it would have to do with Data Contracts which you did not show in your example.

Here is what i found in the MSDN doc. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: see below, there is a section `Simple Enumerations` that is my case

Comment: The clause under simple states
"You can use simple enumerations when you do not need to customize the enumeration's data contract name and namespace and the enumeration member values." You are trying to adjust the values.